# ExtJS6 - Change Grid Column Default Sort Direction from ASC to DESC

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have a grid linked to a remote store with a remote sorting enabled.

When I click on the grid's header for the first time it sets the column order to be ascending, then descending on the second click.

Is there a way to make the first click to go into the descending order for certain columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.. It took quite a bit of time to figure this out, seems like there is no direct API to alter the default direction.

This is what i figured finally, you need to update the defaultSortDirection of sorters in the store.

```
    store.getSorters().$sortable.setDefaultSortDirection('DESC');
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17tu)

**Update**

If you want to apply default sort direction at column level, then you could override the toggleSortState method at column level.

```
       columns: [{
            dataIndex: 'id',
            text: 'ID',
            width: 50,
            /**
             * Overriding this function to Change the Default Sort Order.
             */
            toggleSortState: function() {
                if (this.isSortable()) {
                    var me = this,
                        grid = me.up('tablepanel'),
                        store = grid.store,
                        sortParam = me.getSortParam(),
                        direction = undefined;

                    if(!store.getSorters().get(sortParam)) {
                        direction = 'DESC';
                    }                        
                    this.sort(direction);
                }
            },
        }
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17u2)

Comment: Thanks it works, the only downside is that it changes it for all fields, do you think there is a way to have it applied only to selected ones?

Comment: Updated my Answer, Please Check.